# Get all field names from magento model

Tags: php, magento

How can I get all field names from an object like "order" without creating or loading this object?

Example:

```
Model: sales/order
```

With a loaded order and the getData() method I get an array of various field names like:

```
shipping_tax_amount
grand_total
base_tax_amount
```

How can I get these field names without an order? In my case it must be possible to access to this fields even if there is no order at the magento shop.

Answer (score 6):

```
  $resource = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource');
   $readConnection = $resource->getConnection('core_read');  
    /**
     * Get the table name
     */
    $tableName = $resource->getTableName('sales/order');

$saleafield=$readConnection->describeTable($tableName);
var_dump($saleafield);
```

Comment: Is it save to use the fields from the database table? If it's possible, I would like to avoid a direct database access and use some magento methods. How does it behave, if the magento shop uses flat tables like `sales/flat_order`? Are there any problems?